how to let ROS know my robot is front wheel diff drive?
the robot is ros controlled but the problem is that, it has wheels in front and caster at back, so when it turns around its axis, when near the wall it collides with the wall, we are using trajectory planner as local and global planner and localization is being done using amcl, is there any work around to let ros know that there are wheels at the front instead of middle so you have to make some adjustments to turn?

I am currently using a similarly built robot, and found that declaring a custom footprint, while making sure that my base_link frame was on the axis of rotation was enough for smac_hybrid and RPP to keep me from hitting anything, even in close quarters. I did have to slightly inflate the footprint on the back, to allow for more careful rotation. See attached image for example.


I don't think so, since ROS navigation is only meant for differential drive and holonomic robots. However, a kind of hacky workaround might be to change the navigation parameters to try to guide the robot to stay further away from obstacles by increasing its footprint in the costmap comman params file. Or you can write your own custom local planner plugin and use that instead of ROS's local planner, which would be the more elegant solution but might take longer to implement.

This answer is not correct. The move_base planners will handle this situation correctly if the origin and footprint of the robot are defined properly.
